# Java rename process name

Tags: java, process

So I was thinking can you change the java process name to something different than java.exe or javaw.exe. I have read that you can do it with Launch4j but this makes it a .exe file and I want the file to remain with a .jar extension.

Comment: We don not need more homework or any at all

Comment: What’s in a name? That which we call java by any other name would work as well.

Comment: To run java.exe with a different name you need to copy it to a file with the name you want and run it. You can use your `myjava.exe -jar original.jar` Renaming the JAR won't change the name of EXE.